# How to recover Administrator password for Windows Server 2003 VMWare image

Tags: windows-server-2003, password-recovery

Ok - I confess, I changed the admin password and misspelled it when entering it in our password bank.

Is there a way to retrieve it?

We are using Windows Server Console.

System Rescue CD has a utility call ntpass - though it seems it can only reset the password not recover it.

[Ophcrack support/FAQ](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/ophcrack/index.php?title=Ophcrack_Support)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) is worth taking a look at. It's saved me numerous times, and is perfect for when you want to retrieve the password, rather than change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [OphCrack](http://geeksaresexy.blogspot.com/2006/04/cracking-your-windows-sam-database-in.html) as previously recommended.  This should allow you to load a sam file from a different computer, even offline.  So, you'll need to pull a file off the system in question.  Possibly located at

> c:\Winnt\system32\Config\SAM

Answer (score 1):

OphCrack should work for your needs

Answer (score 0):

EBCD - Emergency Boot CD

It will let you set a new admin password.  I haven't tried it on a VMware image, but I've saved my bacon a few times on physical servers.

[How to use EBCD](http://www.linglom.com/2007/08/16/how-to-reset-administrator-password-on-windows-using-ebcd/)

It seems EBCD is no longer maintained.  Here's one that I have seen a few recommendations for
[How to use pc-login-now](http://www.linglom.com/2008/09/23/how-to-reset-administrator-password-on-windows-using-pc-login-now/)

Comment: thanks Brad, I really need to recover the password because i don't want to bring down the live image.